# envelope icon disappeared after using \includepdf

Tags: pdf, include

I am using \inludepdf to attach a pdf file, which has an envelope icon, into a new document.

[image]

After attaching this pdf file, this envelope icon disappeared in the new document.

[image]

How can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: depends what the envelope is. If it is an annotation you would have to readd it, annotations get lost when you include a pdf.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the reply! I don't know if it's an annotation. It is just an envelope icon used to mark the contact person in the pdf I got. But how to add it back if it is an annotation?